# Bernoulli distribution problem?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I need some help to solve the following probability problem.

**Problem:** We believe 20% of the population living nearby a factory are alergic to a certain polluting. Suppose we pick up randomly 13 people of this population. What is the probability that at least 4 people between them are allergic to that polluting?

**Attempt:** There's an underlying Bernoulli distribution in this problem. Let $X$ be the random variable which counts the numbers of allergic people in the given population. The probability that a person is allergic is $p=0.2$ whereas the probability the person is not allergic is $q=1-p=0.8$. Hence, the probability that there are $k$ persons allergic among the $n=13$ is $$P(X=k)=\binom{13}{k} 0.2^k \cdot 0.8^{13-k}.$$ Hence, the probability we're looking for should be $$P(X\geq 4)=P(X=4)+P(X=5)+\ldots+P(X=13).$$ When I do the computations I find $$P(X\geq 4)=0.2526.$$
However, this doesn't match the answer I've been given $0,9006$.

So, where is the problem in my reasoning?

Thanks

Comment: Your solution seems to be right. Is the other answer reliable? Where does this problem come from?

Comment: Thanks. It's not pretty much reliable. It is from a collection of exercises I found on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you are correct and the answer you are given is wrong:

$P(X \ge 4) = 1 - (P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3))$
$P(X \ge 4) = 1 - (\binom{13}{0}\times0.8^{13} + \binom{13}{1}\times0.2\times0.8^{12} + \binom{13}{2}\times0.2^2\times0.8^{11}+\binom{13}{3}\times0.2^3\times0.8^{10})$
$P(X \ge 4) = 0.252675690496$